# Losing records when converting DataFrame to dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I parse a CSV file into a Dataframe. 10,000 records go in, no problems.
Two columns one 'ID', one 'Reviews'.

I try to convert the DF into a dictionary where keys = 'ID', and values = 'Reviews'.

For some reason the new dictionary only contains 680 records.

```
#read csv data file
data = pd.read_csv("Movie_reviews.csv",
                   delimiter='\t',
                   header=None,names=['ID','Reviews'])
reviews = data.set_index('ID').to_dict().get('Reviews')
len(reviews)
```

output  is 680

If I don't append '.get('Reviews')' everything is one big record.

the Dataframe 'data' looks like this

```
               ID                                            Reviews
1      076780192X  it always amazes me how people can rate the DV...
2      0767821599  This movie is okay, but, its not worth what th...
3      0782008380  If you love the Highlander 1 movie and the ser...
4      0767726227  This is a great classic collection, if you lik...
5      0780621832  This is the second of John Ford and John Wayne...
6      0310263662  I am an evangelical Christian who believes in ...
7      0767809270  Federal law, in one of its numerous unfunded m...
```

Comment: Are the IDs unique?

Comment: @JackHoman yes all values under column 'ID' are unique.

Comment: Without being able to see the full dataset, it's kind of hard to tell what's happening. Everything you're doing looks correct. The only thing that would make sense is if `len(data['ID'].unique()) == 680`

Comment: Upon checking it is. Is there a way to automatically set keys in their place?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "automatically set keys in their place". Keys in a dictionary have to be unique.

Comment: @JackHoman As in add data['Reviews'] as values to the dictionary, and unique keys auto generate. Incremental numbers would be fine. I know I could use a loop, I'm just wondering if their is a better way.

Comment: should just be `data.to_dict().get('Reviews')`

Comment: @JackHoman Brilliant thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone else.

The id's for the movie reviews were not all unique. The .nunique() function revealed that as suggested by @YOLO.

Assigning only the values (Reviews) to the dictionary automatically added unique keys as suggested by @JackHoman resolving my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

**Method 1:**

```
reviews = data.set_index('ID')['Reviews'].to_dict()
```

**Method 2:** Here we convert reviews to a list for each ID so that we don't lose any information.

```
reviews = data.groupby('ID')['Reviews'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Comment: unfortunately that still produces only 680 records

Comment: @JamesFisher Can you check the count of unique ID in your data frame?

Comment: 10,000, same goes for data['Reviews']

Comment: @JamesFisher no, check for output of `data['ID'].nunique()`

Comment: Interesting the output is 680. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JamesFisher Isn't the answer correct then? I've added another method.

Comment: That method does not work unfortunately. Letting the dictionary set the keys itself seems to work fine.